# ListView ItemTapped / ItemSelect is not firing when ListView row contains Expander

Tags: listview, xamarin, expander

My original idea is when I tap on an InvoiceLine, the data of the labels within the Expander body should change accordingly. So when I click on the line, ItemTapped chatches the ItemSelected object and passes it to the ViewModel, where the InvoiceLine property's set method changes the labels' data. But when I tap on the Expander, ItemTapped (and ItemSelect) is not firing, only when I click outside the expander within the listview row.

I can't use Expander's "Tapped" event either, because I can't extract the InvoiceLine data from the listview.

My XAML code:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Invoice.LineItems}" Margin="10" ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped" ItemSelected="ListView_ItemSelected" HasUnevenRows="true">
            <ListView.Header>
                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="4*,*">
                    <Label Text="Tétel neve" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <Label Text="Nettó érték" Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </ListView.Header>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Expander Margin="0,10">
                            <Expander.Header>
                                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="4*,*">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding ItemData}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding NetValue}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Expander.Header>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding E_QuantityUnit}"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding E_UnitPrice}"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding E_VATCode}"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding E_NetValue}"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding E_VATValue}"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding E_GrossValue}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Expander>
                        
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

My View:

```
public InvoiceDetailPage(Invoice invoice, int direction)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ((InvoiceDetailViewModel)this.BindingContext).Invoice = invoice;
    }



    private void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        InvoiceLine line = e.Item as InvoiceLine;
        ((InvoiceDetailViewModel)this.BindingContext).SelectedLine = line;
    }

    private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        InvoiceLine line = e.SelectedItem as InvoiceLine;
        ((InvoiceDetailViewModel)this.BindingContext).SelectedLine = line;
    }
```

And my ViewModel:

```
    private Invoice _invoice;

    public Invoice Invoice
    {
        get { return _invoice; }
        set 
        { 
            _invoice = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged();

        }
    }

    private InvoiceLine _selectedLine;

    public InvoiceLine SelectedLine
    {
        get { return _selectedLine; }
        set 
        { 
            _selectedLine = value;
            E_QuantityUnit = value.Quantity + " " + value.Unit;
            E_UnitPrice = value.UnitPrice + " " + Invoice.Currency;
            E_NetValue = value.NetValue + " " + Invoice.Currency;
            E_VATValue = value.VATValue + " " + Invoice.Currency;
            E_GrossValue = value.GrossValue + " " + Invoice.Currency;
            int tr = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(value.VATCode, out tr))
                E_VATCode = value.VATCode + "%";
            else
                E_VATCode = value.VATCode;
        }
    }


    private string _quantityUnit;

    public string E_QuantityUnit
    {
        get { return _quantityUnit; }
        set { _quantityUnit = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private string _unitPrice;

    public string E_UnitPrice
    {
        get { return _unitPrice; }
        set { _unitPrice = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private string _netValue;

    public string E_NetValue
    {
        get { return _netValue; }
        set { _netValue = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private string _vatValue;

    public string E_VATValue
    {
        get { return _vatValue; }
        set { _vatValue = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private string _grossValue;

    public string E_GrossValue
    {
        get { return _grossValue; }
        set { _grossValue = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private string _vatCode;

    public string E_VATCode
    {
        get { return _vatCode; }
        set { _vatCode = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
```

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: you can use the Expander's Tapped event and just extract the data you need from the BindingContext

Comment: you can use `Expander expander = sender as Expander; InvoiceLine invoice = (InvoiceLine)expander.BindingContext;` to get InvoiceLine data from the listview in  Expander's Tapped.